# How do I get rid of long load times when loading the single player map list?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am getting long load times when I try to load up the single player map list when creating an AI game, when I load up the same list, or presumably the same list, when under multiplayer it loads in seconds, single player I have clocked up to two minutes. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? I only have a dozen or so custom maps downloaded, but I have experienced this behavior since the beginning. I do get some long load times, around a minute, when loading up missions during the campaign but nowhere near the wait of trying to load that list. I assume that my mission load times are due to my harddrive being slow, my de-fragmentation and system checks run nightly. I do have Defender and Kaspersky running but they are approved applications for each.

Comment: This sounds like your disk might be failing, try to check it's S.M.A.R.T. information with a program like HDTune and do an error check too. Besides removing your custom maps and reinstalling StarCraft II there isn't much that you can do on the gaming side of this question, you might want to consider to get this question migrated to the Super User site. Just flag and ask them to migrate it...

Comment: @TomWij: No, this is an issue with SCII. For some reason it just takes ages to load the map list for single player custom games.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin: No, if it would be an issue with SCII then why isn't there a large share of users that experience this problem? It's either the reasons I listed or the virus scanners, because I'm not experiencing this issue.

Comment: @TomWij: The issue exists for some people but not for others. The fact that you don't experience it puts you in the latter category.

Comment: @Bora: Still, that doesn't make it a SCII issue.

Comment: Same here, load times between 3 and 8 minutes. I play lots of other games without trouble. Most recently BulletStorm, so I don't see why SC is having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't take too unbearably long for me to load the "Play Versus AI" map list, it takes significantly longer than loading the multiplayer "Custom Games" list.

As a work around you can also create single player games against AI from the multiplayer screen. If you choose "Custom Game" and only add AI opponents you basically have a single player game against the computer. If you are heading for the various achievements for playing against AI opponents you even have to create the game this way. For "Play Versus AI" games there will be no achievements awarded.

Comment: To be honest I use the Single Player environment to run cheats so I can practice map strategies/scenarios without the fear of being wiped. You cannot use the cheats in the multiplayer environment. The cheats are not good for battle strategies but great for setting up mechanics and practicing speed builds.

Comment: Isn't that similar to the multiplayer map YABOT where you can practice build orders?

Comment: I don't know I have never played YABOT, I stopped installing maps until I can build a scrubber to remove them or Blizzard adds into the software.